# libGL error with Linux target of OpenFL

Tags: linux, opengl, haxe, openfl

I'm planning on doing game development with Haxe, utilizing its C++ target, and for that I chose the HaxeFlixel framework, which uses OpenFL as its backend.  The "hello world" test runs just fine with flash, HTML5 seems to work (minus sound), though I'm not planning on using either of those, as the game I wish to create would be a desktop game that runs natively.

However, when I tried to run the HaxeFlixel hello world example with the target set to native linux, the test program crashed on startup and gave me the following errors:

```
libGL: screen 0 does not appear to be DRI2 capable
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/tls/swrast_dri.so
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/swrast_dri.so
libGL: Can't open configuration file /home/zauber/.drirc: No such file or directory.
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
X Error of failed request:  GLXUnsupportedPrivateRequest
  Major opcode of failed request:  153 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  16 (X_GLXVendorPrivate)
  Serial number of failed request:  211
  Current serial number in output stream:  213
```

I'm at a loss as to how to fix the problem.  I've never seen anything like it, and all other 3D software and games I have run just fine.  I asked on the HaxeFlixel forums, but was only told that it might be a bug in OpenFL.  That seems to be the case since I have the same problem with Awe6, another game framework that uses OpenFL.

I've done a google search for similar issues, but turned up pretty much nothing.  I already have all the relevant libraries that I should have (mesa, nVidia drivers, dri2, 32bit libs), and all the solutions I found pretty much pointed to installing a specific library, which I already had installed.

So far, I have asked on both the OpenFL forums and on the IRC channel, and in both cases I was completely ignored.  I really need to get this problem fixed because unless I do, I cannot proceed with my gamedev project.

For reference, my system is running 64bit Linux Mint 16, Linux kernel 3.11.0-12, and nVidia drivers 319.32

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For reference, my system is running 64bit Linux Mint 16, Linux kernel 3.11.0-12, and nVidia drivers 319.32

Then something in your system configuration is completely messed up: For some reason your program loads a `libGL.so` provided by the Mesa drivers instead of the NVidia drivers `libGL.so`. The telltale sign is, that the loaded `libGL` complains about DRI2 not being available. NVidia's proprietary drivers don't use or support DRI2. DRI2 is the low level state tracker API of Mesa.

Make sure your system is properly configured. Most importantly make sure that none of the libraries, frameworks, etc. you use did something foolish, like bundling up a `libGL.so`.

Comment: Right now, I'm assuming that OpenFL may have done something foolish, since no other programs are having trouble.  And I haven't ever really messed with system configuration at all, beyond installing libs.

Comment: @ZauberParacelsus: Some fools think that OpenGL was a redistributable library and link Mesa's libGL statically or hardcode the Mesa libGL.so path. Which leads to all sort of problems. I suggest you use the tool `ldd` on every library file you use and look which of them link against libGL.so. Then rebuild those from sources and file a bug.

Comment: Yeah, though first I think I'm going to give some serious thought to whether or not I want to continue down the Haxe/OpenFL route.  I chose it because it seemed easier, but as they say, "the easy road is usually mined".

Comment: Based on a quick google search, it seems that people on distros other than Ubuntu are having trouble, apparently because the prebuilt binaries target Ubuntu.  So, my system configuration's problem apparently is "this isn't enough like Ubuntu".